# Use of Non-Blocking Assignment in Testbench : Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have two questions regarding the use of Non-Blocking assignments in testbench.

1. Can we use blocking assignment in always @(posedge clk) w.r.t testbench? I think we can use as we dont have to worry about hardware. But I need confirmation.
2. I have used the following code in my testbench but it doesn't work as expected.

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
```

while((state==2'd3) && (x!=OUT_MAX_SIZE_32) && (count_done==4'd4))
begin

$display("a[%d] :%h, %d",l,a[l],x); 

 a[l] <= {b[x][31], b[x][30], b[x][29], b[x][28], b[x][27], b[x][26], b[x][25], b[x][24]};  
 a[l+1] <= {b[x][23], b[x][22], b[x][21], b[x][20], b[x][19], b[x][18], b[x][17], b[x][16]};
 a[l+2] <= {b[x][15], b[x][14], b[x][13], b[x][12], b[x][11], b[x][10], b[x][9], b[x][8]};  
 a[l+3] <= {b[x][7], b[x][6], b[x][5], b[x][4], b[x][3], b[x][2], b[x][1], b[x][0]} ;   

 x <= x+1;
 l <= l+4;

end

end

What is happening is **x** and **l** are not incrementing if I use non-blocking assignments. But if I use blocking assignments, it works as expected. I need help in analyzing it.

Comment: This is out of topic: If no asynchronous circuit involve in your project, you might want to use `if` statement instead of `while` statement in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-blocking assignments can always be used in test bench code. This becomes an **infinite** loop by use of *non-blocking assignments*.

Referring to SystemVerilog LRM 1800-2012 section 10.4.2,

> The non blocking procedural assignment allows assignment scheduling without blocking the procedural flow.

Referring to section 4.9.4,

> A non blocking assignment statement (see 10.4.2) always computes the updated value and schedules the update as an NBA update event, either in the current time step if the delay is zero or as a future event if the delay is nonzero.

Here, at the *posedge* of clock, lets say *x=0* so it is assuming *while* loop is executed. The RHS of non-blocking assignments are evaluated in active region, while the actual assignments are done in NBA region.

So, increment of *x* to 1 is *scheduled* in **NBA** region of the **same** time-stamp. Also, since it  is a non-blocking statement, the condition of while loop is checked again in active region without blocking anything (getting **x=0** again). Again, *x* is scheduled to be incremented in **NBA** region and this loop goes on **forever**. Hence you are not able to increment **x**. Similar comments applies to l.

While, using **blocking** assignments, the value is **immediately** assigned to the LHS of expression, hence x/l increases.

Also, `$display` executed in **Active region**, so you'll not be able to get value of x as 1. Following image shall give you clear idea about this.

[image: Event regions]

For more information on *event regions*, refer to [CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events.pdf) paper.

Comment: Awsome explanation...Thanks for that :) So do you think I have to worry about using blocking assignments in this ? I mean do I need to find another way of implementing this part using **NBA**?

Comment: I think using blocking assignments will be a better option. Here, I only some rough ideas, use **#1 or some other delay** before NBA statement, but this is **not** a good coding practice. It could be great if you remove while loop and use if condition as `if(x!=OUT_MAX_SIZE_32 && ...)` or some other logic manipulation may be done.

Answer (score 3):

You can and should use non-blocking assignments in your testbench. A simulator does not know the difference between what is you design and your testbench. You need to code both in a way to prevent race conditions.

From the code that you show, I can't see why it would make any difference unless there are other assignments to `x` and `l` elsewhere that you are not showing.

Comment: The only other place where I have used **x** and **l** is the **initial** block where I have initialized both of them to zero.